# Single slave - multiple master MySQL replication

Tags: mysql-replication

I need to replicate different MySQL databases from multiple servers into a single slave server. How can this be done? is there a way to define multiple master hosts?

Answer (score 0):

Your best way of doing this is using tungeten replicator with like a fan-in setup

https://code.google.com/p/tungsten-replicator/

You will be pretty much running one replicator per "master" server and the single slave with have the same number of replicators running for each master db you want slaved into it.

You have to use a 3rd party replication app since it's impossible to do with mysql'd built in replication